# Let $G =\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ and $x \circ y = 2xy$ be a binary operation on $G$. Determine whether $(G, \circ)$ is a group or not.

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

I tried to solve with binary operations but I couldn't. How or in what way can I solve it?

Comment: Show whether the operation is associative, there is a unit element and each element has an inverse.

Comment: You have to show that it satisfies the group axioms: identity element, existence of the inverse, associativity

Comment: You were faster...

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a group.

Clearly, $G$ is closed under this operation. We now check the other axioms:
Associativity: It's easily checked hat $(x \circ y) \circ z = x \circ (y \circ z) = 4xyz$.
Identity: $\frac 12$ works here.
Inverse: Take $y = \frac{1}{4x}$.

Since all axioms are satisfied, $G$ with the operation $\circ$ is a group.

Comment: Thanks, and edited